# Qt 5.9 - Exception at 0x0 due to deprecated call of glLoadIdentity

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl

I have the following Code written by a classmate of mine (we are working a project):

```
//inside cqtopencvviewergl.cpp
void CQtOpenCVViewerGl::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    makeCurrent();

    glViewport(0, 0, (GLint)(width), (GLint)(height));

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(0, width, -height, 0, 0, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    recalculatePosition();

    emit imageSizeChanged(mRenderWidth, mRenderHeight);

    updateScene();
}
```

The call of `glLoadIdentity()` leads to an `Exception at 0x0, code: 0x0000005` according to the Debugger which is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\cdb.exe` in my case.

I know that the function is deprecated. But I am very confused about all information sources about what I should do about it. So I will work you through the disorientation in hope you can help me...

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19746384/5233188) answer the Exception occurs because the functions used are deprecated. But the question differs because I (or we) include openGL quite differently:

At the top of the `cqtopencvviewergl.cpp` we include the following:

```
#include "include/Gui/cqtopencvviewergl.h"
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <QPalette>
```

And at the top of the `cqtopencvviewergl.h` we include:

```
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_2_0>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
```

So we are using Qt classes to call the openGL functions. I took a look at the Code and it seems Qt handles the deprecation itself.

Also according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308499/5233188) answer Qt *supports all current Desktop OpenGL versions*.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17823163/5233188) answer of the asker to the question [*How to replace following (deprecated) OpenGL functions?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17735112/5233188) the *Windows offline installers are by default ANGLE based*. I used the offline installer...

According to [this](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5_on_Windows_ANGLE_and_OpenGL) entry in the qt wiki *To compile Qt with ANGLE* I *have to have a Direct X SDK installed*. However I am sceptical whether I really need this if I use `QOpenGLFunctions` and `QOpenGLFunctions_2_0`...

According to the wiki entry the `Direct X SDK` is part of the `Windows SDK` so I am also sceptical that I already have *ANGLE* due to the fact that I already have a few Windows SDKs:

[image]

Also according to [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html) article I should use `configure -opengl dynamic`ly and because I use Windows I tried to find out where to call `configure` and found `configure.bat -opengl desktop` in [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html) article. So wanted to run `configure.bat -opengl dynamic` but I could not find the `configure.bat` anywhere in the `C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1` directory...

I use the following Qt Kit:

[image]

I am the only one (of 6 people in the project) who has that problem. Normally my questions are more precisely but I am lost here. What should I do ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be [`QOpenGLFunctions_2_0::glLoadIdentity()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions-2-0.html#glLoadIdentity)? It looks like you're calling the opengl function directly.

Comment: @JornVernee No, the call leads to `QOpenGLFunctions_2_0::glLoadIdentity()`...

Comment: Stop using ANGLE with compatibility OpenGL stuff. If you want the old stuff, you have to use a *real* OpenGL implementation, not the ANGLE stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was quite simple...

According to [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html) article the *The loading mechanism can be configured through the `QT_OPENGL` environment variable and the following application attributes*...

So I added `QT_OPENGL` set to `desktop` as a systen environment variable:

> Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables

[image]

I am sure my computer hates me... Cheers!